# Reset angular material form select to placeholder

Tags: angular

I have select, and I want to change it back to its placeholder value on a reset button click.

I tried setting the value to undefined, but it does not change back. What is the best way to do this?

I have a reset button with, and it currently sets the NGModel to undefined and '', but it doesn't change it from the value selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the value to `null`

`<button (click)="areaSelected = null">reset</button>`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k4xmfs?file=app/select-value-binding-example.html)

Comment: Ploppy, this only works if you are not using the placeholder option for the select statement. I cannot add an extra option. I added a bigger code snippet to show what I mean.

Comment: I updated the demo, you don't need any additional option.

Comment: Something though seems quite weird, it looks like you are not using Angular Material as stated in the title of your question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still having trouble reseting to a placeholder. I see your code works with a mat-label. I'll keep digging around.